How can I dynamically load items into a RecyclerView?
When I load my RecyclerView that holds all my drinkitems it loads only enough into it to fill up the screen. However, If I take a look at the items that were loaded into drinkList all the items are there.
Here is what my RecyclerView shows when I scroll to the bottom of the list of items

Here are the items that are loaded into drinkList (I have boxed in what is being shown in the RecyclerView)

And here is my code for the RecyclerView
class FavoritedDrinksFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var favoritedDrinkRecyclerView: RecyclerView
    private var adapter: DrinkAdapter? = DrinkAdapter(emptyList())
    private var callbacks: NavCallbacks? =null

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        callbacks = context as NavCallbacks?
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_favorited_drinks, container, false)
        favoritedDrinkRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.favorited_drink_recycler_view)
        favoritedDrinkRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        favoritedDrinkRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
        setNestedScrollingEnabled(favoritedDrinkRecyclerView, false)
        return view
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)


        var drinks: List<FavoriteDrinkItem> = fetchDrinksFromFile("favoriteDrinks.txt")
        favoritedDrinkRecyclerView.adapter = DrinkAdapter(drinks)
    }

    private fun fetchDrinksFromFile(fileName: String): List<FavoriteDrinkItem> {

        var drinkList = mutableListOf<FavoriteDrinkItem>()

        //File Setup
        val path = context!!.filesDir
        val directory = File(path, "LET")
        directory.mkdirs()
        val inputFile = File(directory, fileName)

        //Reader
        val reader = BufferedReader(FileReader(inputFile))

        //Loop through file and build list
        reader.forEachLine {
            val drinkItem = Gson().fromJson(it, FavoriteDrinkItem::class.java)
            drinkList.add(drinkItem)

        }
        reader.close()
        return drinkList
    }

    inner class DrinkHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view), View.OnClickListener {
        private lateinit var drink: FavoriteDrinkItem

        var drinkNameTextView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.drink_name)
        var drinkImageImageView: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.drink_image)

        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
        }

        fun bind(drink: FavoriteDrinkItem){
            this.drink = drink

            drinkNameTextView.text = this.drink.name.toString()

            getImageFromURL(drink.thumbnail.toString(),drinkImageImageView)
        }

        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            callbacks?.onDrinkSelected(this.drink)
        }
    }

    private inner class DrinkAdapter(var drinks: List<FavoriteDrinkItem>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<DrinkHolder>() {


        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): DrinkHolder {
            val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_favorited_drink, parent, false)
            return DrinkHolder(view)
        }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return drinks.size
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DrinkHolder, position: Int) {
            val drink = drinks[position]
            holder.bind(drink)
        }
    }

    private fun getImageFromURL(url: String, imageView: ImageView) {
        Picasso.get().load(url).into(imageView)
    }

}

I am unsure of a way to either fully load all the drinkitems into the RecyclerView all at once or a way to dynamically add items as I scroll.
